# Allocating beads from a circular necklace

Tags: combinatorics

There is a circular necklace with $n$ beads. There are two people. 
Each person attaches a value to each bead. For each person, the sum of all values is $0$. There is a given some integer $k<n/2$. The goal is to allocate $2 k$ beads in one of the two following ways:

1. Give each person a disjoint string of $k$ adjacent beads whose total value for that person is at least $0$, or -
2. Give both people a string of $2 k$ adjacent beads whose total value for both people is at least $0$.

This is always doable when $k=1$. *Proof*: since the sum of all values is $0$, each person has at least one bead with value at least $0$. Let's call such a bead a "good bead". If one of the people has two or more good beads, then we can give each person a good bead and we satisfy condition 1.

Otherwise, both people have exactly one good bead and it is the same one, say, bead number $i$. Since the sum of values of all beads is 0, the value of $i$ plus the value of $i+1 (\mod{n})$ must be more than 0 for both people. Hence this string satisfies condition 2.

MY QUESTION: Is this possible for any $k\in [1,n/2]$?

Comment: I guess in 1 the strings of adjacent beads have to be disjoint.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes, indeed.

Comment: This question is related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/242112/34461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be impossible already for $n=5$ and $k=2$. A circular sequence of pairs of bead values is $$(2,-3), (2,2), (-3,2), (2,-3),(-3,2).$$ Case 1 is impossible because the only two adjacent beads whose total value is at least $0$ is the first and the second bead for the first person and the second and the third bead for the second person.  Case 2 is impossible because there is no bead with both negative values.

Comment: Thanks! In case you are interested, the question comes from trying to prove the conjecture in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05470  Your example does not show that the conjecture is false, but it shows that the way by which I wanted to prove it does not work...